# android eclipse avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbie that needs some help on getting the AVD running with my app. I've been developing C code for decades, but I have to admit the Eclipse/AVD setup has me stumped! I'm following the 'HelloWorld' tutorials on the developer.android website (and some others) and everything seems to be working OK, up to the point where I try to run it on the AVD simulator.  I'm not getting any warnings, the Eclipse build/run output window says that everything is installed OK and the AVD does startup and run. Eclipse says that my app is loading, but it never runs. All I get is the simulator window with "ANDROID" on the screen and the buttons on the right-hand side.

I've got Eclipse Indigo and r18 of the Android PlugIn (I tried to install Helios, but the Eclipse website directed me to Indigo!). Is Indigo OK for running the simulator, or do I specifically need Helios? I also have Java 1.7.

The API level I have installed is Level 15 (v4.xxx of Android, I think). Don't know if I need a lower version to get my tutorial app to run, but level 15 is the only one I can select when setting up a device in the AVD manager.

I've been trying to get this going for days, trying all sorts of switches and buttons, but to no avail. Before I start uninstalling everything and reinstalling, can anyone advise if  there is anything I might be missing, or has tripped over this problem themselves and found a way around it?  Something that always trips up new starters maybe? Or do I need to go back to scratch?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: make your AVD with android 2.2 that is API level 8, for that you require 2.2 API. Using Java 1.6 is better

Comment: How long have you waited for the avd to start? First time you start it it can take a very long time depending on you computer hardware. Around 15 minutes is what I have experience on slow hardware. It will start quicker once you have a snapshot to start from.

Comment: I've been going for the highest level available to me so far (15), thinking that would work best.  I'll try 2.2 as you suggest, but does that mean there's a problem with higher levels?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long are you leaving your emulator running after you attempt to launch your application? The Android OS can take a long time to boot up in the emulator. If it's stuck on the "ANDROID" screen then you're either not waiting long enough or there's something wrong with your emulator. It should eventually boot into the normal Android lock screen or home screen just like a device.

You can launch your emulator ahead of attempting to run your app by opening the Android Virtual Device Manager (toolbar icon in Eclipse, if installed properly) and then selecting an emulator and clicking the "Start" button. If you don't have any emulators listed, then you need to create one by clicking the "New..." button.

Comment: OK, sounds like I need to wait longer for it to start. I'm giving it about 10 minutes, which I thought was plenty, but I'll start it up and go make a cuppa next time! I need to reinstall everything anyway, so I'll go for Eclipse Helios (instead of Indigo) and Java1.6.   Thaks for the suggestions!